# How to Redirection and apply TLS with single web server multiple ports using RewriteEngine and ProxyPassReverse in Apache configuration

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, https, tls1.2, proxypass

I'm running into a very serious problem.
Hope someone kind can help.

Please see the code below first.
This is part of my Apache configuration.

---

First, the URL of the target web server is http://localhost:30001 ~ 30010. Identifies the site to be accessed through each PORT.

When I receive input as "http://localhost/wksp/30001", I use RewriteEngine to make it "http://localhost:30001". This part works without any problems.

However, I tried to apply TLS and run "https" through ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse again, but it is very difficult.

From what I understand, ProxyPassReverse accesses "http://localhost:[PORT]/" at first, but then communicates with Proxy through "https://localhost/".

Therefore, when communicating with the https protocol, the PORT cannot be dynamically acquired. For example, if http://localhost:30001 is the target, you need to communicate with the proxy server through port 30001.

In my code now, when HTTPS=on, PORT is written as 30001, but what I want is to keep holding the variable $1 when HTTPS=off.

If you have another approach, that's fine. lots of advice Thank.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

...

SSLEngine On

ProxyPreserveHost On
SSLProxyEngine On
ProxyRequests Off
RequestHeader set Front-End-Https "On"

...

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/wksp/(.*) http://localhost:$1 [P]
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:$1

<Location />
Order allow,deny
Allow from all

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond "%{HTTPS}" =off
RewriteRule ^:(.*) http://localhost:$1/ [P]
ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:$1/

RewriteCond "%{HTTPS}" =on
ProxyPass http://localhost:30001/
ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:30001/
</Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

If HTTPS=on, if you change the url port of ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse to $1, the following error is displayed.

```
httpd[1584880]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 55 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/wksp-tls.conf:
ProxyPass Unable to parse URL: http://localhost:$1/
```